# Running a software from a different folder

Tags: command-line

I want to run software for genomics data using Plink. My software is located in one folder and the required data files are in another folder. I can run easily if I put all files in the plink software folder. I would like to run plink commands directly from the data folder. Is there a way, I can directly call plink commands from a different folder.

Comment: is [this reference](http://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/download.shtml) of help? It gived guidance on how to run `plink` and the path variable.

Comment: Please note that it is packaged at 1.07 as https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/plink .